Allow lan clients access to vpn on router
I am trying to have my local area network use a vpn connection on my linux router. I successfully setup the openvpn client using nordvpn and configured split tunneling so I can use both interfaces, I don't want the vpn for everything. I am able to ping 8.8.8.8 over both interface, tun0 and eno1s0. The issue I have is letting the other systems on my lan be able to use this connection by forwarding over the vpn interface tun0. Forwarding over the wan enp1s0 is working fine, the problem is when I change the forward rule to point to tun0 nothing gets forwarded Is it a forwarding or routing problem?
openvpn client.conf file:

client
dev tun
proto udp

remote 146.70.71.51 1194

route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
route-metric 200
pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway

resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 0
ping-timer-rem
reneg-sec 0
comp-lzo no
verify-x509-name CN=ch368.nordvpn.com

remote-cert-tls server

verb 3
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
auth-user-pass nordvpn.txt
auth-nocache

(certificates are omitted)


$ip route

default via 192.168.1.254 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.200 metric 102 
10.100.0.0/16 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.100.0.2 
172.16.2.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.2.1 metric 101 
172.16.3.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.3.1 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.200 metric 102 


$ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:ec:ac:cd:65:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.200/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 50577sec preferred_lft 50577sec
3: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:ec:ac:cd:65:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.2.1/24 brd 172.16.2.255 scope global noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:ec:ac:cd:65:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.3.1/24 brd 172.16.3.255 scope global noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:ec:ac:cd:65:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
22: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.100.0.2/16 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


nftables:

# Flush the rule set
flush ruleset

table ip filter {
  chain INPUT_FILTER {
    # By default, drop all traffic unless it meets a filter criteria.
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;

    # Drop loopback network traffic that is not within RFC loopback network space.
    iif "lo" ip daddr != { 127.0.0.0/8 } drop

    # Allow loopback.
    iif "lo" accept

    # Allow established connections on Aenp2s0LL interfaces.
    ct state { established } accept

    # Allow SSH INPUT from LAN with rate limit.
    iifname enp2s0 ip saddr { 172.16.2.0/24 } tcp dport { 22 } limit rate 5/minute ct state { established, new } accept

    # Allow ICMP and IGMP INPUT from LAN, IOT witenp2s0h rate limit.
    iifname enp2s0 ip saddr { 172.16.2.0/24 } ip protocol { icmp, igmp } limit rate 2/second accept
    iifname enp3s0 ip saddr { 172.16.3.0/24 } ip protocol { icmp, igmp } limit rate 2/second accept

    # Allow DNS INPUT from LAN, IOT.
    iifname enp2s0 ip saddr { 172.16.2.0/24 } udp dport { 53 } ct state { established, new } accept
    iifname enp3s0 ip saddr { 172.16.3.0/24 } udp dport { 53 } ct state { established, new } accept

    # Allow DHCP INPUT from LAN, IOT.
    iifname enp2s0 ip saddr { 172.16.2.0/24 } udp dport { 67 } ct state { established, new } accept
    iifname enp3s0 ip saddr { 172.16.3.0/24 } udp dport { 67 } ct state { established, new } accept
  }
  chain FORWARD_FILTER {
    # By default, drop all traffic unless it meets a filter criteria.
    type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;

    # Allow FORWARD from LAN to WAN. THIS WORKS.
    iifname enp2s0 oifname enp1s0 accept
    iifname enp1s0 oifname enp2s0 ct state { established } accept

    # Allow FORWARD from LAN to VPN. IF I COMMENT OUT ABOVE RULE AND USE THIS. DOES NOT WORK.
    #iifname enp2s0 oifname tun0 accept
    #iifname tun0 oifname enp2s0 ct state { established } accept
 }
  chain OUTPUT_FILTER {
    # By default, drop all traffic unless it meets a filter criteria.
    type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
  }
}
table ip nat {
  chain PREROUTING {
    type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
    # Redirect https port to vpn
    iifname $lan0 tcp dport { 80,443 } dnat 10.100.0.2
  }
  chain POSTROUTING {
    type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
    # Masquerade LAN for internet access.
    iifname $lan0 ip saddr { 172.16.2.0/24 } oif $wan0 snat 192.168.1.200
    # Masquerade LAN for vpn access.
    iifname $lan0 ip saddr { 172.16.2.0/24 } oifname tun0 snat 10.100.0.2
    # Masquerade IOT for internet access.
    iifname $iot0 ip saddr { 172.16.3.0/24 } oif $wan0 snat 192.168.1.200
  }
}


$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding 
  1


How did you set up your routing to forward those clients' packets via tun0?

On the router or lan clients? On the router I posted the output of ip route above. I don't know what else you mean.

It's a routing problem. As the chain name and hook type strongly imply, the forward rules are filter rules – they do not direct where traffic should go; they are consulted after routing and only control whether packets are allowed go through after those have already been directed there by the routing table.
According to your ip route output, you do not have any routes that would direct packets for 8.8.8.8 through tun0, neither from LAN systems nor in general. Merely allowing the packets through by firewall rules will not automatically "attract" them to that interface; you need to specifically route packets there, typically using a 0.0.0.0/0 aka default route to match all destinations.
If you need to route only some clients' traffic through a different interface, define routes in an alternative routing table and hook it up using "policy routing" rules:

Add the needed routes:
ip -4 route add default dev tun0 table 100

Define policy using iif <interface> or from <ip_prefix> conditions to use this table:
ip -4 rule add iif enp2s0 lookup 100

The new table doesn't have any routes to your other LAN subnets. Instead of copying them from the main table, add a 'throw' route that acts like a hole and continues to the main table for LAN destinations (while everything else still uses the "dev tun0" route).
ip -4 route add throw 172.16.0.0/12 table 100


